# Simplifying xoring strings

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I have written the following function to `xor` two strings but feel it should be possible to write simpler:

```
import Data.Bits (xor)
import Data.Char (ord, chr)

-- xors strings of equal length
stringXor :: String -> String -> String
stringXor s t = map chr $ zipWith xor (f s) (f t) where
    f = map ord
```

It seems like you should be able not to have at least the first `map` but I couldn't get zipping with the composition `chr . xor` to work.

Does there exist some useful identitites/formulas involving `zipWith` and `map` ?

I am new to Haskell so if there is a simplification without too much pointfree magic, it would be nice to see :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you could simplify your version using `on` and `fmap`:

```
import Data.Function (on)

stringXor :: String -> String -> String
stringXor = zipWith (fmap chr . xor) `on` map ord
```

also `fmap chr .` could be `(chr.) .` but I find the first one more convenient to type.

**EDIT**

You can even simplify it to:

```
stringXor = zipWith (fmap chr . xor `on` ord)
```

and now we've eliminated the two `map`s.